# how to split apache log by hour

Tags: apache, logging, awk

I have an 30Gb's apache log file.Ex:

```
10.16.131.126 - xxxxx [30/Sep/2014:11:27:20 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/atlas/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 404 "-" "SVN/1.6.11 (r934486) neon/0.25.5"
10.16.131.126 - xxxxxx [30/Sep/2014:11:27:20 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/atlas/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 404 "-" "SVN/1.6.11 (r934486) neon/0.25.5"
10.16.131.126 - xxxxx [30/Sep/2014:11:27:20 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/atlas/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 404 "-" "SVN/1.6.11 (r934486) neon/0.25.5"
```

I want to use awk to split this log file by hours .I have an method,But I think it is stupid. this method is:

```
awk '$4~/[0-9][0-9][/][A-Z][a-z][a-z][/][0-9]+[:]01/' $1  > /data/log_analysis/log_data/$day_time/01.log)
awk '$4~/[0-9][0-9][/][A-Z][a-z][a-z][/][0-9]+[:]02/' $1  > /data/log_analysis/log_data/$day_time/02.log)
awk '$4~/[0-9][0-9][/][A-Z][a-z][a-z][/][0-9]+[:]03/' $1  > /data/log_analysis/log_data/$day_time/03.log)
.....
```

Do you have better method to resolve this problem?thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the split function to parse the date, and then redirect to a corresponding file:

```
awk '{split($4, a, ":"); print > "out." a[2]}' file
```

Comment: Well done! I was thinking on something like `match()` but this is quite cleaner and nicer.